# Find roots for a range of parameters in Maxima

Tags: maxima

In Maxima I have an expression that I want to find the roots for.

However it contains a parameter *l* and I want to get the roots for a list of different values of this *l*.

Is there a way to do this without having to do them one at a time?

Comment: John, it will help a lot to say exactly what is the expression in question. Without knowing the expression, I would say that if the list of I values is not too big, then solving for each one seems to be a workable approach.

Comment: @RobertDodier thanks, I was able to do what I needed using " makelist(subst([l=a], my_expression),a, 0.25, 1, 0.05);" (this gives me a list of copies of my expression with the parameter l replaced with values ranging from 0.25 to 1 in steps of 0.05). I just didn't really know about subst before so I didn't really know how to ask the question!